# Labels das colunas no pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, gráfico, matplotlib

Oi, então eu estou tentando fazer um gráfico de barra e linha junto, e até o momento esteve tudo certo até o momento em que eu tentei mudar o nome das colunas e por os valores acima do ponto de referência, eu estou usando o Pandas e o matplotlib, o código que eu tenho tentado fazer funcionar é este:

```
def generateGraph(labels, bar_data, line_data, name="Grafico"):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd

    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.5,3.5]
    plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
    df = pd.DataFrame(bar_data, columns=[labels[0]])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(line_data, columns=[labels[1]])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(num=name)
    
    df[labels[0]].plot(kind='bar', color='blue')
    df2[labels[1]].plot(kind='line', marker=".", color='red', ms=10)

    plt.show()



generateGraph(["Coluna 1","Coluna 2"], [500,580], [320,400], name="Grafico")
```

atualmente o gráfico está assim:

[image: grafico]

mas eu gostaria que ele ficasse assim:

[image: grafico esperado]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excelente trabalho colocando o código!

Como nao estou no computador, aqui vai bem rápido do celular. Apenas adicione a linha abaixo.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(num=name)

df[labels[0]].plot(kind='bar', color='blue')
df2[labels[1]].plot(kind='line', marker=".", color='red', ms=10)

ax.set_xticklabels(labels) # nova linha para o seu código

plt.show()
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente !, você tem alguma ideia de como posso colocar os números também? eu estou literalmente torrando os neurônios nessa

Comment: @NatanSalazar , Por favor, aceite a resposta acime, para fechar a perguntar e reconhecer o autor da resposta. Aqui está um exemplo concreto....quem procura acha ;-) https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html   depois de algumas tentativas, escreve a pergunta aqui com as suas tentativas, se necessário. Sucesso